# How to stop UINavigationBar title from animating while push transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

Is there any way to stop the titleView on UINavigationBar to animate when I push/pop view controllers. TitleView for each screen is same (app's logo).

Currently when I push a view, titleView on the navigation bar also slide with the view.

Comment: add your other view passing code .

Comment: Use UINavigationController instead of UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 1):

Set the title of the navigation item in each view controller to an empty string  and add `UILabel` subview to the navigation bar:

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds];
titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Roman"
                                  size:20.f];
titleLabel.text = @"TEST TITLE";
titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:titleLabel];
```

This should give you a static title that doesn't move when switching between view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

Comment: NKB, this will prevent the push animation between the view controllers too.

Comment: Yes, It will but since the button animation is handled by the UINavigationController, this is one way.

Comment: If you wish to handle it, one other option is to override the pushViewController method and modify the code. Something similar to the code here http://www.hanspinckaers.com/custom-action-on-back-button-uinavigationcontroller

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.navigationItem.title=@"";

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

A feasible solution is:

Use  `UINavigationController` delegate methods to find out when the **UIViewController** is being shown. Then for each UIViewController, need to make a boolean variable like `isInitialized` property, which help you to determine when the UIViewController is being pushed on the stack, or when it's being shown upon back of next view controller.

*Your `FirstViewController`:*

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            if self.isInitialized {
                var navigationBarAnimation = CATransition()
                navigationBarAnimation.duration = 1.5
                navigationBarAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
                navigationBarAnimation.type = kCATransitionFade
                navigationBarAnimation.subtype = kCATransitionFade
                navigationBarAnimation.removedOnCompletion = true
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar?.layer?.addAnimation(navigationBarAnimation, forKey: nil)
                }
                else 
                {
                        self.isInitialized = true;
                }
        }
}

func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            if self.isInitialized {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar?.layer?.removeAllAnimations()
            }
        }
}
```

*Your `SecondViewController`:*

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            if !self.isInitialized {
                var navigationBarAnimation = CATransition()
                navigationBarAnimation.duration = 1.5
                navigationBarAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
                navigationBarAnimation.type = kCATransitionFade
                navigationBarAnimation.subtype = kCATransitionFade
                navigationBarAnimation.removedOnCompletion = true
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar?.layer?.addAnimation(navigationBarAnimation, forKey: nil)
                        self.isInitialized = true;
                }
        }
}

func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            if self.isInitialized {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar?.layer?.removeAllAnimations()
            }
        }
}
```